# Changing Postmaster File Name in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.4

I have two instances of PostgreSQL with master-slave replication between them and want to use GlusterFS. Everything works fine until the second instance wants to store the data in the GlusterFS. because the postmaster file has the same name in both instances they conflict with each other.

Is there a way to rename the postmaster.pid file so it won't conflict with each other?

Or is there any other way to use two PostgreSQL instances with GlusterFS?.

Comment: `postmaster.pid` exists for a reason; a Postgres server needs exclusive write access to its data directory. Running two instances against the same data directory at the same time will destroy it. Making changes to the data directory of a running server (e.g. via file system replication) will result in catastrophic failure. Why do you want to use Gluster? If you want Postgres replication, why not use [Postgres replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/high-availability.html)?

Comment: There is master-slave replication implemented but the requirement is read and write on both nodes. Currently it is not possible, or is it?

Comment: And yes postmaster does exist for a reason, Is there any way that while starting the server the the postmaster.pid file is created with a different name?. Or if there is a way for an active active configuration, A free solution please mention it here.